# Implementing Periodic Process in UWP, MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, scheduled-tasks

I'm building an small App that gather data from website. and I managed to gather data.

Following picture depicts what my app does.

[image]

when I click the button "시작", my App get html of the specific page, and get data from it. This works are done in ViewModel class, and I bind the result data to ViewPage, observing mvvm pattern I think.

Following source code shows logic that I wrote for my program.

```
public class MainPageViewModel : Observable
{

    public SiseDataList dataList { get; set; } = new SiseDataList();

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
         ButtonClick = new RelayCommand(Click);
    }

    public async void Click()
    {
        // ... omitted .. 
        foreach (var i in tmp_list) 
        {
            if (dataList.Count == 0)
            {
                dataList.Add(i);
            }
            else if (dataList.Last().date < i.date)
            {
                dataList.Add(i);
            }
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("data");
    }
    public RelayCommand ButtonClick { get; set; }
}
```

I bind `data_list` data to `viewPage`, `GridView`.

Now, I think I can say what I want to implement.

If I click "시작" button of my App, I want to execute Click function every 20 seconds.

Luckily, I could easily find the document about periodic work in UWP. Link: [create-a-periodic-work-item](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/uwp/threading-async/create-a-periodic-work-item)

So, I tried to implement that functionality, but I failed.
First I tried the following:

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{
     ButtonClick = new RelayCommand(Regist);
}

public async void Regist()
{
    TimeSpan period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

    ThreadPoolTimer PeriodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(async (source) =>
    {
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
            () =>
            {
                // UI components can be accessed within this scope.
                Click();
            });

    }, period);

}

public async void Click() //...omitted..
```

I put `Click()` function in `Dispatcher`, because I think `Click()` function call `OnPropertyChanged()` from `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
but the Intellisense tells me, It can't find any `Dispatcher` name in context.
So I just right clicked on it and clicked refactoring menu, and then, That sentence becomes `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RunAsync...`
but It does not work. I found `CoreDispatcher` class in documents so I used it. I wrote `CoreDispatcher.RunAsync(....)`, But It is not a static class I can't use that syntax.

I googled and I tried `Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(....)` but it return exception "`Windows.UI.Xaml.Windows.Current.get` returns `null`".

finally, I tried following code.

```
 TimeSpan period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

 ThreadPoolTimer PeriodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((source) =>
 {
     Click();
 }, period);
```

But program crashed while executing `Click` function add element at dataList List, I think other thread(kind of UI thread...?) is watching or holding that list as I bind it to view Page. And It returns exception *"Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)."*

How can I periodically execute a specific function in UWP?

Comment: There is probably no need for explicitly making Dispatcher calls. Just use a [Dispatcher​Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Dispatcher` of the application (which matches the main window's dispatcher):

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
        CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
        () =>
        {
            // UI components can be accessed within this scope.
            Click();
        });
```

The reason your approach did not work is that it is not possible to call `Window.Current.Dispatcher` from non-UI thread, as `Window.Current` is only accessible on UI thread. However `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher` can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: Hi, As your comment, I used `System.Windows.Application.`. but Intellisense tell me that In `System.Windows` Namespace, `Application` namespace does not exist. what is the problem with my App..? I'm embarrassed. I paste your source Into `ThreadPoolTimer PeriodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((source) =>
            { //here// }, period);` In viewmodel part

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :-D!! The namespace is Windows.UI.Xaml, I accidentally used the WPF one. I have updated the answer with the correct code

Comment: Oh my gosh, once again I was completely wrong... Too late here, should go to bed :-D. The correct way to get dispatcher is Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync() . Check the updated answer please :-)

Comment: Updated the code once more, hopefully final time! Sorry for all the confusion

Comment: Thanks, I solved with your source. I have some question to you. first, I want to know how did you know the answer. and second, I found that I wrote `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(...)` , but It works as well. How can It work. Thanks for your kindness. ^^ b... thumb up